# Import SSRS Reports from Development CRM into Production

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

I have created custom reports in SSRS using BIDS in the development instance of CRM. I want to now export/import this report into Production CRM. Can somebody help me here please?

Answer (score 3):

We add SSRS reports to CRM all the time. All you do is click on Reports > New > and from the drop down menu (three choices) select existing file. Select the RDL file (yes, you can simply copy this file from your server to local machine)

Once you selected the RDL file, select where you would like it to be displayed etc from the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article, in the end there is the procedure to upload the RDL file inside CRM

[How To: Creating Custom Report with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 BIDS Fetch Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/10/26/how-to-creating-custom-report-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-bids-fetch-extension.aspx)

Comment: That is how I did in the development instance of CRM. Now that I have my reports working, I would want to export them from development into production. The article talks about what I have already done in development. Is there a way to fetch reports without setting up the environment?

Comment: did you try to import the rdl in your production environment? it throws an error?

Comment: It does not support RDL file import. Only .CSV, .txt, .xml and .zip are the supported file types.

Comment: You clicked on Import Data, you can't upload the RDL from there. Follow the instructions on the link I wrote before: navigate to Reports, create a new report by clicking New at the top left, Select Existing File as the Report Type, the File Location should now be enabled, Browse to that .RDL file that was created by the project and upload it.

Comment: The RDL file is on another server. Can I just copy the RDL file from that server into my local drive and then upload it?

Comment: Yes, after you create the new report and upload the file try to run it, if doesn't work write down the error.

Comment: It says : Report cannot be displayed (rsProcessingAborted)

Comment: I suggest to open a new question, specifying that you moved a report from development to production (and write if is onpremise or online environment) how is your connection string inside the dataset and all the relevant informations. Will be more visible and maybe you get more replies.

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it.